# Creating a Keras Layer that executes a scikit-learn classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I am trying to integrate in a keras model a "black box" sklearn classifier (it is a GradientBoostingClassifier this time, but I would like to make it as general as possible).

The input should be processed by the keras model and the last layer is a custom made keras layer that executes the classifier.

I've come this far:

```
class SKLearnLayer(Layer):
    classifier = None
    def __init__(self, output_dim,classifier, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.trainable = False
        self.classifier = classifier
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.built = True
    def call(self, x):
        #Eager execution must be enabled
        inp = x.numpy()
        out = self.classifier.predict(inp)
        return tf.convert_to_tensor(out)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

I am instantiating the layer in this way:

`output_c = self.SKLearnLayer(1, classifier = self.classifier)(output_b)`
(where output_b is a normal Keras layer).

But I am getting some weird errors such as

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

(eager execution is enabled).

Anyone has any idea on what I have done incorrectly?

Comment: Insert this line `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)` above `ind = x.numpy()` in `call` function and try.

Comment: It didn't work :( . I get this error when I am instantiating the layer.... I can't understand exactly why this happens